# PHP doesnt get the full path of file

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing this to get the directory and the file uploaded in the database.

```
<?php
require_once('inc/config.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot connect :'.mysqli_error());
$sql = "SELECT * FROM profile_info WHERE username = '" . 
$_SESSION['username'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$resume_name = $row['file_name'];

$resume_location ='resume/'.$resume_name;
$resume_ok = "<a href='".$resume_location."'>Resume</a>";
?>
```

This grabs the resume name and when i want to get the file name together with the directory, it just shows only the directory and not the file name like this

`localhost:82/resume` instead of like this 
`localhost:82/resume/Jannan.pdf` what could be wrong?

Comment: probably you get null at this point $resume_name = $row['file_name'];

Comment: the name is not coming in the $row, try to print_r($row) and check or show the output

Comment: (ignoring all that's wrong here) does $resume_location contain what you think?

Comment: @DamienPirsy, kindly explain

Answer (score 0):

Set SITE URL in variable and give the full path with directory of href

```
 <?php
    require_once('inc/config.php');
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot connect :'.mysqli_error());

    $SITE_URL =  "http://localhost:82/";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile_info WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $resume_name = $row['file_name'];

    $resume_location = $SITE_URL.'resume/'.$resume_name;
    $resume_ok = "<a href='".$resume_location."'>Resume</a>";

    ?>
```

Comment: doenst Work, sorry. it just shows the localhost:82/resume/